# Solution population model with dual system

Tags: partial-differential-equations, adjoint-operators

I have this population model here:

\begin{align}
    \begin{cases}
    \frac{\partial}{\partial t} p(t,a,x) + \frac{\partial}{\partial a} (\Gamma_0 p(t,a,x)) + \frac{\partial}{\partial x} (\Gamma_1(a,x) p(t,a,x)) \\\ = -(L(a,x) + F(a,x) + d_1) p(t,a,x) + G(N(t))q(t,a,x),\\
    \frac{\partial}{\partial t} q(t,a,x) = L(a,x) p(t,a,x) - (G(N(t)) + d_2)q(t,a,x).
    \end{cases}
    \label{Hauptmodell Grundformel}
\end{align}
with initial conditons
\begin{align}
    p(0,a,x) = p_i(a,x), \;\; a \geq 0, \,x \geq 0,
    \label{Hauptmodell Anfangsbedingung p}
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
    q(0,a,x) = q_i(a,x), \;\; a \geq 0, \,x \geq 0,
    \label{Hauptmodell Anfangsbedingung q}
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
    p(t,0,x) = \frac{2}{\Gamma_0} \int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty f(a,x,y) \, p(t,a,y) \, da \, dy.
\end{align}

and get this eigenvalue problem

\begin{align}
    \begin{cases}
    \lambda P + \frac{\partial (\Gamma_0 P)}{\partial a}  + \frac{\partial (\Gamma_1(a,x) P) }{\partial x} = -(L(a,x) + F(a,x) + d_1) P + \tilde{G}Q,\\
    (\lambda + \tilde{G} + d_2)Q = L(a,x) P,\\
     P(0,x) = \frac{2}{\Gamma_0} \int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty f(a,x,y) \, P(a,y) \, da \, dy.
    \end{cases}
    \label{stationäre Lösung}
\end{align}

and then this dual/ adjoint problem
\begin{align}
    \begin{cases}
    \lambda \varphi - \Gamma_0 \frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial a} - \Gamma_1(a,x) \frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial x} -2\int_0^\infty \varphi(0,y) f(a,y,x) \,dy\\
    = -(L(a,x) + F(a,x) + d_1) \varphi + L(a,x) \psi,\\
    (\lambda + \tilde{G} + d_2)\psi = \tilde{G} \varphi
    \label{adjungiertes System}
    \end{cases}
\end{align}

with normalisation
\begin{align*}
    \int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty \left(\varphi(a,x) P(a,x) + \psi(a,x) Q(a,x)\right)\,da\,dx = 1.
\end{align*}.

And now they say that solutions of the normal population model in the beginning satisfies this condition here:
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty \left(\varphi(a,x)p(t,a,x) + \psi(a,x)q(t,a,x)\right)\,da\,dx\\
= e^{\lambda t}\int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty \left(\varphi(a,x)p_i(a,x) + \psi(a,x)q_i(a,x)\right)\,da\,dx
\end{align}

Can someone explain how to get this condition in the end?